# How to insert multiple table using auto increment value of one table mysql hibernate in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, auto-increment

I need to insert 2 tables one in flight details and another is passenger details. In passenger details table I need to enter the auto incremented value of `flight_booking_id`.

I am using `Projections.max` to get last inserted `flight_booking_id` but it is a multi-threaded environment so whether there is a transaction which I can able to get auto-incremented value and insert in other table.

Using Hibernate 3 and mysql 5.1.34

Answer (score 0):

Your puzzle hibernate must solve with success. First of all primary key  business must provide hibernate [generators](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-enhanced). The second, connect your passenger entity with flight_booking with [ManyToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) or\and OneToMany relationship. The third, in competitive environment persist entities with pessimistic locking mode (I'm not sure, that its enabled in hibernate 3).